# Does an alternative to .closest() exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is a snippet from my code:

```
$("#myid").append($("p:contains('text')").closest("div").clone());
```

I tried to get the first closest ancestor div-element of p containing 'text'.

I'm looking for an alternative to .closest() because I have to use jquery version 1.2.6.
Do you have got an idea what I'm looking for?

I hope you can help me. I appreciate every hint, piece of code, etc..

Comment: both closest and perent climb up the dom tree

Comment: from jquery.com: .closest( selector ) Returns: jQuery

Description: Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Comment: I see it now. Getting the first ancestor element that matches the selector it is then. Hm.

Comment: if your question has been answered, please mark it as Answered. thanks

Comment: I'll mark it as answered asap ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$('p').parents('div:first')`

should do :)

Comment: Just a question. If There were two p-elements containing the snippet of text I wouldn't get the second p-element, would I?

Comment: yeah, you can get second one using $('p:eq(1)').text();

Comment: Like $("#myid").append($("p:contains('text'):eq").parents('div:first').clone());
? I'm sorry I understand what you mean, but got some problems with the syntax.

Comment: Okay, I tried some things and got what I wanted. $('p').parent('div') does it.

Comment: you can also doing it like this to find a the first element which is have `id`. $('p').parents('[id]:first');

Comment: is there something in pure JS only ?